# Ubuntu Server AUTOSTART

Tags: server

How do I configure the server to restart automatically when the power comes back (after it has been shut down due to outage of power>?

Answer (score 1):

Some BIOSes have a Wake on Power facility. Your hardware needs to support it. It is not a software setting as far as I know.